# Can I use the same SSL certificate to secure web server and mongo server

Tags: php, mongodb, ssl

On a website running PHP and a MongoDB server, users should have access to PHP pages (https) while partners should access MongoDB server directly (over an SSL connection on standard MongoDB port 27017). Is it possible to use the SSL certificate (used for the website) to also secure the MongoDB since they both run on the same physical machine?

Comment: IMO you shouldn't allow any access to the actual database except to the web server. That is what rest interfaces are for which are served through your web server. Having the db open to remote access is a security hole IMO. Really, the db should be on a separate machine behind a firewall and shouldn't be accessible from the web at all but that is sometimes overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same certificate for different applications, same application on different ports, different systems etc and all at the same time - as long as the certificate can be validated and the server is identified by the certificate. This means that the trust chain can be verified (depends on Root-CA installed on the client) and the certificate matches the name which is used to access the system. Note that different application protocols have different rules on how the name will be checked, especially regarding the use of wildcards.

Comment: Ahem, that's too much of an oversimplification. The primary use of SSL certificates is not to provide encryption capabilities, but to positively identify the host you are talking to. Using a host certificate for a different system will lead to problems because the host can not be identified, to be more precise, the certificates Common Name field will not match the DNA name of the host. While there are so called wildcard certificates valid for entire domains, they can not be used to identify an individual host.

Comment: So an attacker which successfully hijacked *any* host of "example.com" can identify himself as part of your domain with an arbitrary name, for example "payments.example.com". Hence, sending data to a host not positively identified, be it encrypted or not, is a bad idea.

Comment: I've tried to make the important parts more clear but at the end I've never said anything about encryption at all, only about the identification part. And no, the attacker can not you an arbitrary name to hjack, because this name must be first in DNS and second must match the certificate and finally the attacker must have access to the private key of the certificate to use it. And if this is the case you are lost anyway and should revoke the certificate as fast as possible.

Comment: Was talking of's wildcard certificate ;)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: even with wildcard the name must be in DNS and the attacker must have access to the private key of the certificate. The risk is not the wildcard, the risk is to have the same private key on lots of hosts which increases the attack surface because it is sufficient to hack one system. But you get the same problem when you have a large installation and multiple IP addresses for the same hostname (load balancing via DNS).

Comment: Good points, still an unnecessary risk with a high potential impact. DNS spoofing, cache poisoning and other attacks may easily pay off. Add only one lazy Sysadmin... ;) Good  point with DNS based load balancing, another point against it ;)